# Correct way to install JML

Tags: java, installation, jml, openjml

I tried to install Java modeling language (JML) and something got wrong.
I use Eclipse IDE, windows 10. I opened Eclipse -> Help -> Install New Software and then I installed using [this](http://jmlspecs.sourceforge.net/openjml-updatesite)

Then, I restarted Eclipse and the new icons appeared in the top menu bar. When I try to compile or to use JML icons Eclipse shown a huge error message. ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jnwi.jpg))

What can I do to fix this? I didn't find a solution on [website](http://www.openjml.org/documentation/installation.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

I am not allow to use the comment function.

Here are my remarks:

1. First, it seems that OpenJML is installed correctly.
2. If the stacktrace belongs to the OpenJML run, it is clearly a case for the issue tracker. The [corresponding line](https://github.com/OpenJML/OpenJML/blob/master/OpenJDK/trunk/langtools/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Enter.java#L502) handles the import multiple packages. Maybe you could try with an [example to from the OpenJML repository](https://github.com/OpenJML/OpenJML/blob/master/OpenJMLTest/testfiles/escConstructor/Parent.java) to verify, that the problem occurs with your Java file only. You could also try openjml on the command line. It behaves like javac with extra options.
3. A minor detail: Something seems odd with the OpenJML versioning. Current version is 0.8.49 (after github releases) from 2020-09-25. Your version 0.8.48, but from the same date.

Comment: Thank You! Still I didn't solve the problem but I found that the error code is 4, so I will try to search for this error in github page mentioned in jml website